# How can I Hide/Get rid of the text on the submit button?

Tags: php, css

I have this submit button that gets an `int` Printed on it by `PHP`. That value is used to run a script. But I don't want to have to see the `int` value on my button, because I have a fancy `CSS Class` linked with it. I've tried all kinds of things, like removing the `echo` from the value, but that way the scrip'd stop working. Then I tried to hide it with CSS, using `display:none;`. and `color: none;` *(whitch I later found out wasn't going to work anyways in any way)*

PHP/HTML Form Snippet:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=$id"?>" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="deleteComment" class="closeButton" style="color: none;" value="<? echo $delComment ?>" />
        </form>
```

CSS

```
.closeButton
{
background-image:url(images/closeimage.png);
width:15px;
height:15px;
float:right;
margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
border:none;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
/*z-index:0;*/
color:#FFF;
}
.closeButton:hover
{
background-color:#000;
background-image:url(images/closeimage_white.png);
color:#000;
}
```

As you can see the texture changes on hover, so setting the text to a color same as the background won't work. (also the texture is multicolored..)

I'm not even much of a beginner anymore but I'm just not able to figure this out! Thanks!

Comment: try the old `text-indent: -9999px` trick :)

Comment: Nice one, thanks for being quick, however that brakes the *:hover event in CSS. The one by @Sean Beck solved this for me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could just set the line-height to something very high like 100px inside your hover, as long as you have the explicit height on the button the text will not appear.

Comment: Going to accept this as the answer tomorrow, no time to wait today for 10 minutes to pass, thanks! [[no new answers needed]]

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the submit input value and use a hidden input to hold your value:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=$id"?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $delComment ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="deleteComment" class="closeButton" style="color: none;" value="" />
</form>
```

By the way your form is sent as `POST` and I doubt that the query string in the `action` (`?id=$id`) will actually be POSTed

Comment: it will. the thing is its already on that page, and then if you use another submit button it will redirect back to index page, so I'm using that to keep the user on the same page. It works. 

Hope you got what I mean.